# RegExp for filtering log messages

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I need to filter log messages based on the log level and a text appearing in the log message. These messages are in the following form:

```
    12/23/2009 17:33:26.379 [INFO] TMSNG.Main Channelset configured with url [http://172.16.34.4:8080/tms-flux/messagebroker/streamingamf]
    12/23/2009 17:33:26.380 [DEBUG] org.springextensions.actionscript.core.command.CompositeCommand Executing composite command '[object CompositeCommand]' in sequence
```

I already have the code below that creates 2 regular expressions (one for the level and one for the text) but I was wondering how I could combine these into one. I tried several combinations, but since my regexp skills are non-existing I couldn't get this to work.

Any hints?

---

Code:

```
private function filterLogMessage(item:Object):Boolean {
  var logMessage:String = String(item);
  var levelFilter:String = getLevelFilter();
  var levelRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(levelFilter, "");
  var textFilter:String = StringUtils.trim(filterTextInput.text);
  var textRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(textFilter, "");
  var match:Boolean = (levelRegExp.test(logMessage) && textRegExp.test(logMessage));
  return match;
}

private function getLevelFilter():String {
  var result:String = "";
  var selectedLevel:String = levelComboBox.selectedLabel;

  switch (selectedLevel) {
    case "DEBUG":
      //result = "\\[(DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR|FATAL)\\]";
      break;
    case "INFO":
      result = "\\[(INFO|WARN|ERROR|FATAL)\\]";
      break;
    case "WARN":
      result = "\\[(WARN|ERROR|FATAL)\\]";
      break;
    case "ERROR":
      result = "\\[(ERROR|FATAL)\\]";
      break;
    case "FATAL":
      result = "\\[(FATAL)\\]";
      break;
    }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick (never worked with flex before, so not entirely sure whether syntax is correct ;-) )

```
private function filterLogMessage(item:Object):Boolean {
    var logMessage:String = String(item);
    var levelFilter:String = getLevelFilter();
    var textFilter:String = StringUtils.trim(filterTextInput.text);
    var filterRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(levelFilter + ".*" + textFilter, "");
    var match:Boolean = (filterRegExp.test(logMessage));
    return match;
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! And it looks so simple ;-) Merci Folke.